# DCOS Adding DNS entries in resolv.conf

Tags: resolve, mesosphere, dcos

We have setup DNS Cnames in our pre prod environment. These DNS entries in resolv.conf are getting overwritten by dcos Component 'Generate resolv.conf'. 
Since we need entries from dcos in addition to our local cname entries, can you please direct how to add nameserver in resolv.conf via dcos so that it does not get overwritten ?

Comment: Found this - https://mesosphere.github.io/mesos-dns/docs/configuration-parameters.html
Let me try if this works.

Comment: Dropped this use case. Name resolution works fine without adding local cname entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it is not reflected in /etc/resolv.conf, the configuration mentioned here https://mesosphere.github.io/mesos-dns/docs/configuration-parameters.html works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add them to the resolvers in config.yml

Comment: additionally, the documentation link would be [HERE](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.12/installing/production/advanced-configuration/configuration-reference/#resolvers)

You need to specify your upstream resolvers in the original cluster's configuration file. This is an advanced method, and the best way to install DC/OS clusters for production @Ehteshaam